# Passing variables in and out of GCM task service

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

I am using the [GCM network manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) and I want to pass the service (specifically to the `onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams)` some objects. From the documentation [taskParams](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/TaskParams) are simply a string and a bundle but I want to pass more complex objects.

How can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: You can pass data via the bundle actually. Its not completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have your custom object implement the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface and use Bundle.putParcelable/Bundle.getParcelable.

It requires a little more effort to use than using Java's native serialization, but it's way faster (and I mean way, WAY faster).

For example:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
```

}

Also you can read [Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)